# Return true if a graph is a disjoint union of paths

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

I am trying to make an if statement with the condidion that a graph is a disjoint union of paths using networkx but I'm not sure how to go about it

I tried deleting an edge (u,v) in each node iteration then checking if the first node in the graph to the first node without the edge (node1 to u) is a path then check the same thing from the second node to the last node (v to node 2).

```
            for i in G1.nodes:
                node_count = node_count+1
                nodes.append(i)
                p = nx.neighbors(G1, i)
                for o in p:
                    neigh.append(o)
                    
                for j in neigh:
                    G1.remove_edge(i, j)
            no = len(nodes)
            for k in range(0, node_count-1):
                path.append(nodes[k])
            if nx.is_path(G1, path):
                for l in range(node_count-1, no-1):
                    path2.append(nodes[l])
                if nx.is_path(G1, path2):
                    return True
```

Comment: Can you show some examples of graphs where this condition is, and isn't, true?

Answer (score 0):

By union of paths, you mean [Path Graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_graph), then we can solve the problem by decomposing our graph into connected components, and then determining if each connected component forms a Path Graph.

(I think) This can be done by checking each connected component has degree sequence `[1, 1, 2 ... 2]`:

```py
import networkx as nx

def is_disjoint_path_union(G):
    for c in nx.connected_components(G):
        n = len(c)
        if n == 1: continue
        if not sorted(dict(nx.subgraph(G, c).degree()).values()) == [1, 1] + [2]*(n - 2):
            return False
    return True
```

Appears to work:

```py
>>> is_disjoint_path_union(nx.disjoint_union(nx.path_graph(3), nx.path_graph(3)))
True
>>> is_disjoint_path_union(nx.complete_graph(3))
False
```

Answer (score 0):

A finite graph G is the disjoint union of paths iff every vertex has degree <= 2 and there are no cycles.

Observations:

- |E| < |V|
- There can be any number of isolated points (degree zero)

Procedure:

- return true if all nodes have degree 0 or 1
- return false if any node has degree > 2
- return false if any node has degree 2 and there are no nodes of degree 1
- return false if the graph has any cycles.
- return true

Cycle detection is linear in this graph because |E| < |V|. One of several fast ways to find cycles is repeatedly using BFS (once per connected component).